# Does MVC and WebApi controller share route table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

Seems by error, I had put my `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...)` under `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(...)` instead of `WebApiConfig.Register(...)`. But even then, the WebApi controller actions seemed to work just fine.

Does this mean that if the MVC controller and Web API controllers are in the same project and namespace, are their routes put into the same Route table?

Comment: Short answer would be yes. They all end up in the same route table. Which also explains why you tend to put api routes before MVC routes and also why there can be route conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are their routes put into the same Route table

Short answer would be yes.

They all end up in the same route table. Which also explains why you tend to put Web API routes before MVC routes and also why there can be route conflicts.

`RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(...)` and `WebApiConfig.Register(...)` are just ways to organize and group related code together.